# Use epstopdf with input files in different folder

Tags: pdftex, latexmk, epstopdf

I've been looking for hours and I still can't find a suitable solution. My problem is, I have a tex file which I must compile with pdflatex and it uses pstricks, so I use epstopdf and stuff. The issue comes from the fact that I have the main file (called libro.tex) in a folder and the input files are in a subfolder. I configured correctly the `TEXINPUTS` variable, so I don't have problems with it.

The problem arises from epstopdf: the external program can't find the input files in the subfolder. I did some research and I included

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\graphicspath{{./libro-algebra-lineal/}}
\epstopdfsetup{outfile=./libro-algebra-lineal/}
```

where `libro-algebra-lineal` is the subfolder, thinking that maybe then it would find the input files. I have this output:

```
entering extended mode
epstopdf ($Id: epstopdf.pl 36129 2015-01-24 00:30:11Z karl $) 2.23
!!! Error: Cannot open y=-1y1_k=1.eps: No such file or directory
```

And it's repeated for every pstrick figure. I configure my options via `latexmk` and GNU `make`, and I can't find any useful option for `epstopdf` program or Ghostscript.

Notes:
- My configuration of pdflatex is, inside my own latexmkrc,

```
$pdflatex = "TEXINPUTS=.:libro-algebra-lineal//:$TEXINPUTS pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=batchmode %O %S";
```

- I can't move the input files from the subfolder, since that's a shared folder.
- I tried the latex, dvips, ps2pdf cycle, but since the document has png pictures as well, ps2pdf didn't work :c

Thanks!